# Compare two arrays for similar values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have two arrays, one I am getting from form request and the other I am getting from a mongoDb query. I want to look for all the items passed in request parameters inside the result obtained in mongodb array.

```
    var userIdArr = ["6fbeb3e28de42200e7e7d36", "56fbde9be618221c1d67f01"];
    var mongoDbResultsArr= [
          {"_id": "56fce5bf7031bd482abdfb8a",
         "userIds": "[56fbeb3e28de42200e7e7d36, 56fbde9be618221c1d67f010]"
          },
          {"_id": "56fd2c22ea0f3664156685ac",
          "userIds": "[56fbeb3e28de42200e7e7d36, 56fbde9be618221c1d67f010, 56f53491886e496e32c68b00]"
              }
            ]
```

Basically I want to search if the values given in userIdArr exists in the 'userIds' key of mongoDbResultsArr. Also if this can be done by writing just mongodb query, or any other better way.

This is how my schema looks like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56fd2c22ea0f3664156685ac"),
"startDateTime" : ISODate("2016-03-31T08:34:59.000Z"),
"endDateTime" : ISODate("2016-03-31T08:34:59.000Z"),
"productId" : "#789990#2",
"applicableThemes" : [ 
    "red"
],
"userIds" : "[56fbeb3e28de42200e7e7d36, 56fbde9be618221c1d67f010, 56f53491886e496e32c68b00]",
"price" : 45,
"dealType" : 1,
"photos" : {
    "dealimageUrl3" : "http://mailers.shopping.indiatimes.com/shopstatic/shopping/images/diwali2013/banner.jpg",
    "dealimageUrl2" : "http://mailers.shopping.indiatimes.com/shopstatic/shopping/images/diwali2013/banner.jpg",
    "dealimageUrl1" : "http://mailers.shopping.indiatimes.com/shopstatic/shopping/images/diwali2013/banner.jpg"
},
"dealDescription" : "Bang Bang deal!!",
"dealName" : "Christmas Special Offer",
"storeId" : "56f5339fe99b1a294818ecbe",
"__v" : 0
```

}

and I am using mongoose ORM.

Comment: If we don't wish to implement it yourself, the [jsdiff library](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) may help you.

Comment: `var s=JSON.stringify(mongoDbResultsArr); userIdArr.filter(a=>s.contains(a))` seems safe enough with long IDs like that...

Comment: `"userIds"` contains a string, and not an array. It's a stringified version of an array. I gues you did not really mean that. Probably have `"userIds": String` in the schema, and that would be incorrect.

Comment: I also suspect that you want to "compare this in the database", however your question title and inclusion of [tag:javascript] has people suggesting JavaScript methods of comparison. May or may not be what you want, but if you want the former then I suggest you make that clearer.

Comment: Comparing in database would be much better if it can be done, basically the array elements may be in any order and I need to find if any element in userIdArr matches with any element in userIds in the mongo schema.

Comment: Something like this - YourModel.find({ userIds: { "$in" : userIdArr} }, ...) @RishikRohan